# How do you sequentially flip each dimension in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, flip

I have encountered the following function in MATLAB that sequentially flips all of the dimensions in a matrix:

```
function X=flipall(X)
    for i=1:ndims(X)
        X = flipdim(X,i);
    end
end
```

Where `X` has dimensions `(M,N,P) = (24,24,100)`.  How can I do this in Python, given that `X` is a NumPy array?

Comment: What is the format of `X` in Python? Is it a list or perhaps a NumPy array?  There is too little information to answer your question.

Comment: @rayryeng - This has to be a numpy array

Comment: Thanks.  You didn't make that clear in your post.

Comment: @rayryeng - Just edited the question :)

Comment: from [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/80abba07ea892e50da3df7e318844f33):  X[[slice(None, None, -1)] * X.ndim]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent to `flipdim` in MATLAB is [`flip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) in `numpy`.  Be advised that this is only available in version 1.12.0.

Therefore, it's simply:

```
import numpy as np

def flipall(X):
    Xcopy = X.copy()
    for i in range(X.ndim):
        Xcopy = np.flip(Xcopy, i)
     return Xcopy
```

As such, you'd simply call it like so:

```
Xflip = flipall(X)
```

However, if you know *a priori* that you have only three dimensions, you can hard code the operation by simply doing:

```
def flipall(X):
    return X[::-1,::-1,::-1]
```

This flips each dimension one right after the other.

---

If you don't have version 1.12.0 (thanks to user hpaulj), you can use `slice` to do the same operation:

```
import numpy as np

def flipall(X):
    return X[[slice(None,None,-1) for _ in X.shape]]
```

Comment: How about this one, X[::-1,::-1,::-1] Will it be the same?

Comment: @Wajih Correct.  That's assuming that you have three dimensions.  The code will work for any amount of dimensions of your `numpy` array.

Comment: Thanks. Python syntax is so confusing at times. Yes the dimension will be 3, so it will work just fine :)

Comment: @Wajih haha! Don't I know it!

Comment: @Wajih btw, you're very welcome and thanks for the accept!

Comment: `x[[slice(None,None,-1) for _ in x.shape]]` for `x` of unknown dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. Didn't know that. I've added that to my post.

Comment: The statement on "this will mutate the array" is wrong, I think. You're creating a new binding. This will change the value that `X` is assigned to. I checked it for the second case compatible with numpy 1.11 at least. You will _have_ to return the array.

Comment: @Praveen I'll remove that statement and will explicitly return.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Praveen I've also tested.  The first way does not create a new binding and it actually does mutate.  The second version does.  To minimize confusion, for the first version I've simply made a new copy of the array and performed the flipping on that new copy and returned it.

Comment: Surprising. I'd have thought that the view object returned by the `flip` method gets bound to `X`. Thanks for the info, and for checking!

Comment: @Praveen yeah it's really weird... ah well. That was a cool experiment to run.  You're very welcome!